# Without expanding, prove that abc can be factored out

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Without expanding, prove that
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix}bc&c^2&b^2\\c^2&ca&a^2\\b^2&a^2&ab\end{vmatrix}=abc\begin{vmatrix}a&c&b\\c&b&a\\b&a&c\end{vmatrix}$$

How should my thinking be when I see a matrix equal its transpose like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can multiply: 

$1$st row by $a$, 

$2$nd row by $b$, 

$3$rd row by $c$,
 and (of course) divide determinant by $abc$ after that:
$$
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
bc & c^2 & b^2 \\
c^2 & ca & a^2 \\
b^2 & a^2 & ab
\end{array}
\right|
=
\dfrac{1}{abc}\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
abc & ac^2 & ab^2 \\
bc^2 & abc & a^2b \\
b^2c & a^2c & abc
\end{array}
\right|.\tag{1}
$$

Then divide: 
$1$st column by $bc$, 
$2$nd column by $ac$, 
$3$rd column by $ab$, 
and (of course) multiply whole result by $bc\cdot ac\cdot ab = a^2b^2c^2$:

$$
(1) = \dfrac{1}{abc}\cdot a^2b^2c^2 
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & c & b \\
c & b & a \\
b & a & c
\end{array}
\right| =
abc 
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & c & b \\
c & b & a \\
b & a & c
\end{array}
\right| .\tag{2}
$$

---

*Note*: this manipulation is correct when $a\ne 0$, $b\ne 0$, $c\ne 0$.
If one of them is zero, then LHS-determinant is equal to $0$ (starting formula is correct too in this case).

Comment: Note, before doing those operations, that if one among $a$, $b$ and $c$ is zero, the matrix has rank $<3$, so it's not restrictive to assume none of the coefficient is $0$.